# Realm.io enterprise edition cost

Tags: realm

How much does realm.io enterprise edition cost? it's my understanding that once you want to have more than one server hosting your realm object server you have to move up to enterprise edition. I don't see a clear starting price nor examples for price on realm's website

Comment: Ask at sales[at]realm.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pricing is scaled. After getting on a call with them they gave us an estimate of $20k/month. For context we are a startup that has not yet released into production.

As mentioned earlier, there is no concrete answer as it depends on usage.

Answer (score 0):

**Enterprise:**

> Pricing scales with use case.

**Professional Edition:**

> 14-day free trial; pricing starts at $1,750 per month.

As per:

- [Realm.io Pricing](https://realm.io/pricing/)